# Android intent to share the audio data into the google drive?

Tags: android, google-drive-api, google-drive-android-api

I tried to share the audio files to google drive by using the below method.Is it possible to share file to google drive by using Intent.createChooser() method and also any permissions to be  added in the Androidmanifest file.
The error was i can't share the file to google drive.Please help me to solve this problem.

```
    Uri uri = Uri.parse(MEDIA_PATH);
    Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
    share.setType("audio/*");
    share.setPackage("com.google.android.apps.docs");
    share.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "Share audio File"));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can do it like that. First you need to [setup your Android to for Drive API](https://developers.google.com/drive/android/get-started). Then check the [Creating Files](https://developers.google.com/drive/android/create-file) docs to know about creating files.

> "You can create files in two ways with the Drive Android API: using
>   the CreateFileActivityBuilder class, or using the createFile() method
>   of the DriveFolder interface"

Here's an Drive [Android demo](https://github.com/googledrive/android-demos/) for your code reference.

Answer (score 0):

Try this method it works for me share the data by using Intent.createChooser().

```
  File files = new File(MEDIA_PATHS);
            Uri u = Uri.fromFile(files);
            arrayList2.add(u);

 Intent share = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE);
                    share.setType("audio/mpeg");
                    share.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, TO);
                    share.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_CC, CC);
                    share.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Your subject");
                    share.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, arrayList2);
                    try {
                        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "Share..."));
                        finish();
                        Log.i("Finished sharing.", "");
                    } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
                        Toast.makeText(CallRecordsActivity.this, "nothing shared.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
```